# Get All Display Specifications in Android Foldable including Closed One

Tags: android, foldable, display-manager, foldable-devices

I want to retrieve display specs for all screen in Foldable devices. `DisplayManager.getDisplays` only return currently active display. I've tried with `displayManager.getDisplays("android.hardware.display.category.ALL_INCLUDING_DISABLED")`, but it only works on Pixel Fold. It doesnt work with Galaxy Z Fold. How can i achieve the same result that can works in all Foldable? Is that possible?